# Spinning up a container per a user login

Tags: docker, containers, lxc

Relatively new to containers.

Looking to spin up a new Kali container on SSH login with X11 forwarding on user login via ssh - is this possible? objective is to not force users to install their own Kali VM

saw dockersh is archived and hasn’t been maintained, just looking for somewhere to start if at all feasible

Comment: I guess you just kick off "docker run ..." from the login shell script..  What have you tried?  it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Reasonable! I saw dockersh was archived and figured there may have been something I was missing. 

I'll give that a shot